# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock not returning anything from parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, block

I'm trying to build a datastore singleton to fetch one instance of my PFObject subclass "Question".   Before I was just fetching the data in my PFQueryTableViewController subclass.  I used this exact code to fetch the objects from parse and it worked but here it doesn't.

I did remember to import `<Parse/Parse.h>` and there definitely is a `Question` class in Parse with data in it so I don't understand why `parseQuestions` is coming up nill.

Any ideas?

DataSource.m

```
@implementation DataSource


+ (instancetype) sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self addQuestionData];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) addQuestionData {
    NSMutableArray *questionItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Question"];

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *parseQuestions, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (Question *q in parseQuestions) {
                self.question.objectId = q.objectId;
                self.question.user = [self loadUser];
                self.question.answers = [self loadAnswers];
                self.question.questionText = q.questionText;

                [questionItems addObject:self.question];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Here is my class in Parse with `questionText` data in it.

[image]

Here is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: How are you determining that the fetch has failed?

Comment: I stop the program right at `if (!error)` and look a the value of parseQuestions which is nil.

Comment: What's the value of `error`?

Comment: `error` is also equal to nil

Comment: Can you post the code where you check the value of the array?

Comment: Are you using ACL on the Question objects? If so, maybe the user who is performing the query does not have access to the objects, and therefore does not see them?

Comment: The ACL permissions are set as Public Read and Write.